# sqlite3 replacement for sqlite_has_more

Tags: php, sqlite

First of thank you for your help.

The code piece "while (sqlite_has_more($dres))" is using sqlite2 and I need sqlite3. If there isn't a replacement for has_more is there another code I can use to still Find whether or not more rows are available?

F.Y.I. The server updated their stuff which included their sqlite and now I have to fix this last peice of code to get the schedule to populate and not give me this error.

> Fatal error: Non-static method SQLite3::open() cannot be called statically in /home/server/public_html/current-list.php on line 57

```
$row_num    = 0;
if ($dbh = SQLite3::open($sked_path))
{
    $qsql = "SELECT rowid,* FROM sked ORDER BY sk_dow_num, sk_time_start, sk_time_end";
    $dres = SQLite3::query($dbh, $qsql);

    if (SQLite3::num_Rows($dres) > 0)
    {
        $last_dow   = "";
        $last_start = "0000";
        $last_end   = "0000";
        while (sqlite_has_more($dres))
        {
            $ska   = Sqlite3Result::fetchArray($dres, SQLITE3_ASSOC);
            $rid   = $ska['rowid'];
            $dow   = $ska['sk_dow_name'];
            $start = $ska['sk_time_start'];
            $end   = $ska['sk_time_end'];
    $title = preg_replace("/<br\s*\/*>/", " ", $ska['sk_show_title']);

            $show_dow   = strtoupper($dow);
            $show_start = strtoupper(formatTimeAmPm($start));
            $show_end   = strtoupper(formatTimeAmPm($end));
            $show_style = "";
            if (stristr($title, "Encore Show"))
                $show_style = " class=\"$text_style\"";
```

Comment: You ask for `sqlite_has_more` yet the error message complains about ` SQLite3::open()` ...

Comment: I was under the impression that the error was because the line wasn't sqlite3 the sqlite_has_more was phased out. I am trying to work around it so the code will work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like ...

```
<?php
$dbh = new SQLite3;
if ( !$dbh->open($sked_path) ) {
    trigger_error('...error handling...', E_USER_ERROR);
}
else {
    $dres = $dbh->query('
        SELECT
            rowid,*
        FROM
            sked
        ORDER BY
            sk_dow_num, sk_time_start, sk_time_end
    ');
    if ( !$dres ) {
        trigger_error('...error handling...', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    else {
        $ska = $dres->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
        if ( !$ska ) {
            onNoRecords();
        }
        else {
            do {
                doSomethingWithRowData($ska);
            }
            while( false!=($ska=$dres->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) );
        }
    }
}
```

(completely untested)